# Is there a way to skip the MiNiFi properties validation?

Tags: validation, version, apache-nifi, apache-minifi

I'm running a MiNiFi flow with MiNiFi version **0.5.0** and passing the data on to a NiFi flow with NiFi version **1.12.1**

Because of the versions gap, the xml that NiFi produces includes a few extra properties for the processor ListFile, that the MiNiFi validator later rejects.

Is there a way to skip the validation, so I won't have to edit the config.yml file to remove these properties?

Thanks in advance.